# how can i move an object while the iphone is being shaken in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am creating an iphone project where I need to make a ball move in the same direction of the shake while the device is being shaken.. and then take a certain speed and path when the shake event ends.

I have searched the net and have only posts that can detect a shake effect after which you will be able to run a preset animation that you want.. and I have found many tutorials where you can make a ball move depending on the tilt of the screen.. however what I would like to do, is make the ball move depending on all criterias: shake rythm, shake speed, and giroscope tilt.. is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To do this accurately you must use [Core Motion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion) framework, specifically [`CMMotionManager`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmmotionmanager) class. Depending on the device capabilities this class provides both accelerometer and gyroscope data.

To get the ball moving in correct way, this would require a function that would translate the received data from `CMMotionManager` into values you can animate. That is hard to guess, so I suggest creating a basic function that detects the force and direction and then tuning the parameters by testing.